# Awk space-delimited file content

Tags: awk

I have a file whose lines I want to split using either space or "_".

Its format is

```
f 5.287102213 _10_ RTR  --- 312 cbr 120 [13a a 6 800] ------- [6:0 20:0 29 20] [15] 1 0

s 5.288000000 _0_ AGT  --- 322 cbr 100 [0 0 0 0] ------- [0:0 2:0 32 0] [18]
```

My awk script is as follows:

```
`#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS="[[:space:]]|_"} # use posix space or underscore for FS

{
action = $1;
time = $2;
sta = $4  ; # shifted here because underscores are delimiters
dest = $6;
app = $10;
pkt_size = $11;

#print $1
#print $2
print $5
#print $4
#print $5
#print $6
#print $7
#print $8
#print $9
#print $10

if( action == "s" && dest == "MAC" && app == "cbr"){
            startTime+=time ;
        count++;        
}

if( action == "r" && dest == "MAC" && app == "cbr"){
            endTime+=time   ;
        receivedSize+=pkt_size  ;               
    }


}`
```

As seen in the above script, from the above script I was expecting RTR to be in $4. 
But I find that the output of $3 is as follows:

```
 RTR  --- 312 cbr 120 [13a a 6 800] ------- [6:0 20:0 29 20] [15] 1 0
 AGT  --- 322 cbr 100 [0 0 0 0] ------- [0:0 2:0 32 0] [18] 0 0

 RTR  --- 322 cbr 100 [0 0 0 0] ------- [0:0 2:0 32 0] [18] 0 0
```

What am I doing wrong? Am new to awk.

Comment: Am sorry I dint mark it correct earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `FS` value to `[[:space:]_]+` to get the tokenization (splitting into fields) you want.

Test it with this statement to see the fields recognized:

```
 awk -F'[[:space:]_]+' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){print i ": " $i}}' \
   <<<'f 5.287102213 _10_ RTR  --- 312 cbr 120 [13a a 6 800] ------- [6:0 20:0 29 20] [15] 1 0'
```

---

The problem with your `FS` value, `[[:space:]]|_`, is that

- it only recognizes *1* character at a time as the separator
- it only recognizes *either* whitespace *or* `_` as the separator.

Note that specifying an explicit `FS` value other than `' '` (a single space) causes awk to look for a *single* instance of that separator, and interprets multiple adjacent instances as separating multiple - and thus *empty* - fields.

Thus, in your case, the spans `<space>_` and `_<space>` each represent not a single separator, but two separators abutting an *empty* field.

If you want *spans* (runs) of a given character or characters from a set to be interpreted as a *single* separator instance, use duplication symbol `+`.

However, the proposed `FS` value, `[[:space:]_]+`, may be *too permissive*, as it would recognize a run of *any mix of* whitespace and `_` chars. as a separator.

To be more restrictive, you could use the following `FS` value:

```
[[:space:]]+_?|_?[[:space:]]+
```

---

That said, if the `_` chars in your input function more like *delimiters* enclosing only *one field*, a better solution may be:

- to use the DEFAULT value of `FS`, which recognizes *runs* of whitespace as delimiters
- to strip the `_` delimiters from field `$3`: `gsub("^_|_$", "", $3)`